# How to find transitive dependencies with dynamic versions in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have a Gradle project with a large set of transitive dependencies (from Spring, Apache, AWS etc).
I want to find out if any them have dynamic versions, e.g. `1.2+`?
Ofc I do not want to search manually through all possible BOMs.
If I build a dependency tree with `gradle dependencies` I get a set of already resolved fixed versions unfortunately.
I guess there is probably another Gradle task/command for this.

The reason for this is that I want to know if I need to use [dependency version locking mechanism](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html).